# Send Socket string from server to specific client

Tags: c#, string, sockets, send

I am using C# language to allow clients that are designed in WPF platform to send string via server to another clients.

But problem with my code is that I am broadcasting from my server to all clients same message while using TCP protocol. I know that TCP is famous with the fact that you can specify endpoint.But I don't know how.

This is what I do in server.

```
foreach (Socket _connectedUsers in clientSockets)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(Message);
    Socket socket = (Socket)_connectedUsers;
    socket.Send(data);
}
```

What this code does is broadcasting message to everyone from a list in clientSockets.

Now the question.

How can I do something like:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(Message);
Socket socket = (Endpoint User IP Address);
socket.Send(data);
```

Comment: You can't broadcast using TCP.

Comment: You are not broadcasting, just sending the same message to all your client connections. So yes, you are already doing it - just for them all. So by using only one clientSocker, you only sending to one specific client. UDP can broadcast.

Comment: @FrankNielsen So, how can I send just to one and specific endpoint? Instead of sending to everyone?

Answer (score 1):

You have to identity the client you want to send the message to, and do the same for only that client socket.

```
var _connectedUser = FindClientById( client.Id, clientSockets );
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(Message);
Socket socket = (Socket)_connectedUser;
socket.Send(data);
```

So you challenge is to identity the clientSocket that represent the client you want to send the message to.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds logically correct. Have you any idea how can I do that?

Comment: That will be a different, and more architectural question. But i think you can similar questions on this site, on how to keep track client connections.

Comment: I was wondering, if you are aware how to convert IPEndPoint to Socket?

Comment: You can not convert it. The IPEndPoint is something the socket either connects to or is listening on.